# extract elements from Ajax-JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, object

I am conversant with PHP but I am a beginner with AJAX, and JSON is driving me crazy.

My PHP script delivers a simple JSON string, e.g.

```
    {"bindings": [ {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "newURI", "regex": "^http://.*"},
    {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "deleteURI", "regex": "^delete.*"}, 
    {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "randomURI", "regex": "^random.*"} ] } I
```

retrieve it as follows:

```
var fillDataMasterTable = $.ajax({          
    url: "/php/PrepareGoogleDataTable.php" +"?"+
                "SensorString="+SensorString + "&"+
                "TableType=" + TableType +"&"+
                "NoAbscissaBins=" + NoAbscissaBins + "&"+
                "DataTableName=" + DataTableName +"&"+
                "TimeUnit=" + TimeUnit +"&"+
                "TimeStart=" + TimeStart,          
    dataType:'json',          
    async: false          
    }).responseText;    

 $('#debug_div').html(fillDataMasterTable);
```

That works fine, and I get my JSON string back. But how can I access the individual values? I tried:

```
          $('#debug_div').html(fillDataMasterTable.bindings);
```

but that just doesn't work. I am certainly doing something abysmally stupid here, and I am a bit ashamed - but I do need some hand-holding to get myself started..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reponseText` is a property of `XMLHttpRequest` object,and it will not be a `JSON` object after request.It'll be a `String`.And it does not metter,whether you specify `"dataType"` as `"json"`.

So you need to convert it to json object:

```
 fillDataMasterTable = JSON.parse(fillDataMasterTable);
```

and then you can access properties like this:

```
 fillDataMasterTable.bindings
```

Comment: @user1042031 I have resolved the OP's problem by my answer.The other stuff (accessing objects) is too straightforward.

Comment: Thanks Engineer, it works - and you rescued my mental health! For my own education, though, I still do not understand the point of Ajax specifying a  `dataType:'json'` option, if said option does not influence the result. Which are the situations in which dataType becomes relevant? Be as it may, my original issue is resolved.

Comment: @aag The answer of "`Which are the situations in which dataType becomes relevant?`" , is simple. "When you use `success:function(data)` callback of `$.ajax`". "Why?"."Because before passing `data` to `success` callback, `jQuery` converts that data to appropriate type specified by `dataType` option".

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery like this :

```
$.each(fillDataMasterTable.bindings, function(i, object) {
            $.each(object, bindings(property, value) {
                $('#debug_div').html(value);
            });
        });
```

Comment: Use this after you parse as said above by @Engineer

Comment: user1042031, this reply is for your [**deleted SO Question**](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:stackoverflow.com/questions/11383338/jsfiddle-javascript-block). I only was going to mention this link may help you [**learn more about jsFiddle**](http://neverindoubtnet.blogspot.com/2012/07/jsfiddle-in-6-minutes.html). Cheers!